# Solving nonlinear multivariable ODEs in Julia

Tags: julia, ode

I have a bunch of coupled nonlinear ODEs whose system could be summarized as follows: 
[image]

Where F,G,H and I are nonlinear functions using all variables and some parameters p that also depend on certain values of variables.

I could either solve it using a for or while loop or some homemade functions but I thought as I am trying to get better at Julia I would try to use the DifferentialEquation.jl that I think will allow quicker/more efficient computation, and of which I have read now different examples as well as part of the documentation.

The problems I have are the following:

- All variables are of different sizes and I have seen examples computing evolution of a vector (I could write all of them as a big big vector but then it would be a pain to retrieve the matrix and also that would mean storing everything at every timestep) but not different sized variable.
- I would need to store all of these variables after one loop (which end I can define by using callbacks), but I only need to store U[1] and U[2] at every time step.

I have not found (yet) any example similar to mine. Can anyone help please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would help if you posted some code demonstrating what you want to achieve in the end, even in the first variant. Or explain what you mean with "All variables are of different sizes" and what matrix you want to extract. There is documentation and also some question/answers here about the direct use of structured data in the state variable.

Comment: At the moment the code I have does that using for loops (so at each time step computing `U=U+rate*F(..),..` for every variable). I would like to re-write it using the DifferentialEquation package. I only need to extract U[1] and U[2] at every timestep and all of the rest at the end of the execution only. The sizes are indicated next to the relevant equations, n is of order 10^2 and m 10^3 at the moment. I am sorry to be so useless but I tried to look for your hint but have not found any related topic, maybe could you send a link please? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is better. I thought I saw an example recently where the state vector was a composite structure of vector/matrix fields, but I can find no indications about such a thing here or in the documentation. Must have been some other library or language. The easiest way would be to have a class containing `U,A,B,C` as fields that has translation functions to and from flat vectors, or even has its fields as views into a flat vector.

Comment: Found it, ArrayPartitions as the first point in https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqDocs.jl/blob/master/docs/src/features/diffeq_arrays.md. Not the interface I remembered, but allows to access the array in some structured way.

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for, as I had tried that but only DifferentialEquations does not allow it.  But it also contains DifferentialEquations.jl so I would be able to use callbacks. Thanks.

Comment: You probably will also need to use the stepper interface, not the one-in-all interface that is commonly used for the examples, to avoid producing long arrays of vectors of large dimension in the returned result of the integration.

Comment: The stepper interface shouldn't be needed. Just turn off saving with `save_everystep=false`, or be explicit like `saveat=[0.1,1.0,2.0]`.